# Issue in accessing WCF service on Citrix Server. Error creating the web proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultproxy' configuration section

Tags: wcf, citrix

I hosted a WCF Service as a Windows Service (`http://localhost:8090/WrapperSvc`). This is running in LocalSystem account. This is hosted in a Citrix server. User with limited access on the Citrix server is able to browse the WCF Service using IE. However, if user tries to access thru Console App, getting below error.

```
Error creating the web proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultproxy' 
configuration section
```

User with Admin access is able to run the Console App and access the WCF Service.

Not sure what rights/ config I am missing to make the limited access permission user to access this WCF Service. Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I couldn't resolve this issue yet. Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?, we stumbled into the same now. Searched on serverfault, but there is nothing to be found with wcf and citrix